# Find a sequence which converges in $X$, but not in $Y$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Find a sequence which converges in $X$, but not in $Y$, for:

- a) $X = \ell^\infty, Y = \ell^2$
- b) $X = \ell^2, Y = \ell^1$

This problem was left as an exercise to a reader and it comes with hints.

a) Since $\ell^\infty$ is a pretty wide space, I tried finding a sequence $x^n$ such that it isn't bounded in $\ell^2$ norm, but each element of the sequence is. So I came up with this sequence where term $\frac1n$ shows $n^3$ times:

$$x^n = (\frac1n, \frac1n, ... ,\frac1n, 0, 0, ...).$$

It is simple to see that $x^n$ converges to $0$ in $\ell^\infty$ as $$\|x^n\|_\infty = \frac1n \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty.$$

On the other hand, $x^n$ is not convergent in $\ell^2$ as it is not bounded in $\ell^2$ because of:

$$\|x^n\|_2^2 = n^3 \frac1{n^2} = n.$$

b) It seems impossible to use the same argument as in a). The hint for both of the problems state that I should find a sequence with norm equal to $1$ in $Y$. Thus I can use:

a) term $\frac1n$ shows $n^2$ times

b) term $\frac1n$ shows $n$ times

$$x^n = (\frac1n, \frac1n, ..., \frac1n, 0, 0, ...).$$

Now for both a) and b)

- in $X$ we have $\|x^n\| = \frac1n \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty$
- in $Y$ we have $\|x^n\| = 1$.

My questions are:

1. Why wouldn't such a sequence $x^n$ with property $\|x^n\| = 1$ be convergent (to a non-zero point)?"
2. Does it generally imply that a sequence with $\|x^n\| \ge 1$ diverges?
3. What if a sequence of linear bounded operators $A_n$ has $\|A_n\| \ge 1$?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: You can easily show that if $x^n\to x$ in $\ell^p$, then $x^n\to x$ pointwise. Thus in your examples, the limit must be equal to the pointwise limit, i.e. the zero sequence.

Comment: @Milten what would pointwise convergence be in case of $\ell^p$ spaces?

Comment: By that I mean $|x_j^n - x_j| \to 0$ for all $j$.

Comment: @Milten Yes, all makes sense now. Thank you. How could I prove this pointwise convergence claim?

Comment: @Milten I think I can see it. For $\ell^\infty$ it's obvious. For other $\ell^p$ we know that each of the series factors converges to zero. Is it enough?

Comment: Yes, looks fine! That being said, it's not too difficult to find a solution to (b) where the norm is infinite. Hint: Aim for $(1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots)$ as the limit sequence, but make sure all of the $x^n$ are in $\ell^1$ for it to be valid.

Comment: By the way, your construction can also work for (b) and give infinite $\ell^1$ norm. You just have to find the right number of $(1/n)$'s to use in $x^n$ – not too few, not too many.

Comment: @Milten I can use the term $\frac1n$ $n$ times and then have convergence to zero in $\ell^2$, but $\|x^n\| = 1$ in $\ell^1\|$. Unfortunately, I can't see how any other amount of terms $\frac1n$ helps me make the sequence unbounded. But now I understand why this sequence can't converge to a non-zero element, and thanks for that again.

Comment: You can also look at $\sqrt{n}x^n$ so that $\|\sqrt{n}x^n\|_{\ell^2} = \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ but $\|\sqrt{n}x^n\|_{\ell^1} =\sqrt{n} \to +\infty$.